# ValueError: Unable to parse datatype from schema. Could not parse datatype: interval year

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, types, pyspark-schema

We use data type dependent logic in Spark 3.2. For `interval year` data type, `DataFrame` methods `schema` and `dtypes` don't seem to work.

Without `interval year` type column, the methods work well:

```py
df1 = spark.range(1)

df1.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = false)

print(df1.schema)
# StructType(List(StructField(id,LongType,false)))

print(df1.dtypes)
# [('id', 'bigint')]
```

But when I add a new column, `schema` and `dtypes` methods start to throw the parsing error:

```py
df2 = df1.withColumn('col_interval_y', F.expr("INTERVAL '2021' YEAR"))

df2.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- id: long (nullable = false)
#  |-- col_interval_y: interval year (nullable = false)

print(df2.schema)
# ValueError: Unable to parse datatype from schema. Could not parse datatype: interval year

print(df2.dtypes)
# ValueError: Unable to parse datatype from schema. Could not parse datatype: interval year
```

For our logic to work, we need to access column data types of a dataframe. How can we access the type `interval year` in Spark 3.2? (Spark 3.5 doesn't throw errors, but we cannot use it yet)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that it's possible to use underlying `_jdf`.

The following recreates the result of `dtypes`:

```py
jdtypes = [(x.name(), x.dataType().typeName()) for x in df2._jdf.schema().fields()]
print(jdtypes)
# [('id', 'long'), ('col_interval_y', 'interval year')]
```